# How to add additional permissions for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. Here is the code in the program file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

In the `appSettings.json`

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "my_client_id",
    "ClientSecret": "client_value",
    "Domain": "my_tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "my_tenant_id",
    "Audience": "https://example.onmicrosoft.com/my_client_id"
}
```

I have decorated my controller with `[Authorize]`.

In Fiddler/Postman I first run

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

passing in

```
grant_type (client_credentials), 
client_id (my_client_id), 
client_secret (client_secret),
scope (https://example.onmicrosoft.com/my_client_id/.default)
```

Which returns the token, allowing me to pass this bearer token into my call to the Web API and it returns data if the token is correct else a 401 error.

All runs as I expect.

I was trying to add permissions (maybe called `Roles` or `Scope`) so I could tailor my API where certain methods were read-only and others had write permissions.

How could I achieve that as I can't find any document to help and others don't use `Audience` in the `appSettings` config file (shown above) but have it as scope but then I don't know how to add it to my current code?

Answer (score 0):

To add permissions to your `ASP.NET Core Web API`, check this [Github Sample code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration.md) (Thanks @ cilwerner).

- You have to define scopes in your app registration in the Azure portal. And add the scopes to your API permissions in the app registration and configure the API with the scopes.

Add scopes in the app registration as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Adding the scopes to API permissions

app registration-API permissions.
Select `Add a permission` and choose `My APIs`.

In program.cs use this

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi().AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); 
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.AddPolicy("ReadPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api://Client_id/read")); 
    options.AddPolicy("WritePolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api://my_client_id/write")); }); 

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization("ReadPolicy", "WritePolicy"); 
app.Run();
```

```
"AzureAd":
 {  
   "Instance":  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "ClientId":  "my_client_id",
   "ClientSecret":  "client_value",  
   "Domain":  "tenant_id",  
   "TenantId":  "tenant_id",  
   "Scopes":  "api://client_id/read    api://Client_id/write"  
}
```

For further information refer to the [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet) and [MSDoc2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore)

Comment: If i use the code as is and remove Audience from the json file i get error that value is required?

Comment: Yes, the Audience property in the appSettings.json file is used to specify the resource identifier for your API. If you remove this property, you will get an error because the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi method requires this value to be set.
If you want to use scopes instead of an audience, you can specify the scopes in the Scopes property of the MicrosoftIdentityOptions object in the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Maybe i dont understand the difference between Audience and Scope, but could i use both or does it have to be one or the other?

Comment: Check this MSdoc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes) for more information.